# python: dictionary from "key=value"

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How can i split a **single** key-value pair into dictionary in python?

```
s = "x=y"
sp = s.split('=', 1)
for key,value in sp:
    print(key, "==", value)
```

I did not find anything helpful, except using nested `for` and `dict()` which is really unclear.

Comment: Down vote ? Why. There is no answer for this, and for python newbie this is just not so clear.

Comment: Your question is perfectly fine, you have a code attempt and everything. There shouldn't be any downvote according to the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split and unpack:

```
s = "x=y"
key,value = s.split('=', 1)
print(key, "==", value)
x == y

items = ["x=y","i=j","a=b"]

for ele in items:
   key, value = ele.split('=', 1)
   print(key, "==", value)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is simple. I tried this, probably did a mistake so it wasn't working.

Comment: Do you actually just want a dict or do you want to see the key/values also?

Comment: I have a function that handles such strings, and to check key/value (for their meanings) i thought it's better to do not use [indexes] on 'split' result.

Comment: So they are being passed to a function in pairs?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = "x=y"
>>> dict([s.split('=', 1)])
{'x': 'y'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make it a 1-tuple - I'd also suggest using `str.partition` instead of `str.split`, eg:

```
>>> s = "x=y"
>>> dict((s.partition('=')[::2],))
{'x': 'y'}
```

That way, you'll end up with `''` as the value for where no `=` is present. If there should be an `=` then `str.split` it, and let the exception propagate.

If only everything after the last `=` should be the value, then `str.rpartition` it instead, eg:

```
>>> s = "x=y=z"
>>> dict((s.rpartition('=')[::2],))
{'x=y': 'z'}
```

If you really need to guarantee there's a `=` and only one, so ensuring you have a key/val pair, then:

```
try:
    d = dict((s.split('=', 2),))
except ValueError:
    pass # do something appropriate - there's no `=` or more than one
```

And, an alternative, since you're only dealing with a **single** value, and as strings are immutable, it won't cause problems further down the line, then:

```
>>> s = 'x=y'
>>> dict.fromkeys(*s.split('=', 2))
{'x': 'y'}
```

But seriously don't use `dict.fromkeys` for this - it's a FYI - it works in this circumstance, but I certainly wouldn't enjoy seeing it in the code base of a production system :)

Comment: Yeah this is how you would optimise it, I thought about it but thought it maybe overcomplicates things for such a small operation

Comment: `partition` is faster but I don't agree that it will be helpful when no `=` is present.  In the case where there is no `=` an `Exception` should be raised and also on an empty string. I don't think there should be a dictionary of `{'': ''}`

Comment: @jamylak think I've covered every base... struggling to think of another way to do this now...

Comment: Your last approach is very hacky cause thats not what `dict.fromkeys` was meant for haha. Another way of doing this is simply  `>>> k, v = s.split('=', 1)`
`>>> {k: v}`
`{'x': 'y'}`

Comment: @jamylak it was more an FYI - I certainly wouldn't use it :p - updated to reflect my thoughts on that

Answer (score -1):

```
    In [1]: s = "x=y"
    In [2]: sp = s.split('=', 1)
    In [3]: i=iter(sp)
    In [4]: new_dict=dict(zip(i,i))
    In [5]: new_dict
    Out[5]: {'x': 'y'}
```

**dict-** It is used for creating a new dictionary.
**zip-** It is used for iterating over two lists in parallel.
**iter-** Returns a iterator.